# Employment status scale graphic

Tags: discussion, jobs

What does the employment status scale graphic mean?

[image]
<sub>(source: [adzerk.net](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3092.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F**k My Life -> My job is Bliss

My job is horrible ----> My job is awesome